# Hiding information in HTML for JavaScript to find

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I want to add information to an HTML page that will be visible to JavaScript but not to the end-user. I want to keep the original HTML page as simple as possible. One solution would be to use non-standard tags, such as `<custom> ... </custom>`

I am aware of the [official way of adding custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements), but my purpose is not to show anything on-screen, so using the `CustomElementRegistry` seems overkill.

Here's my use case. I am creating an "aided reader" web application for people who are learning English. My JavaScript code adds `<span>` elements to an ordinary HTML page, enclosing words which are new to the reader. For example, JavaScript code will change the plain HTML ...

```
<p>The word "thought" may be new to elementary learners.</p>
```

... to:

```
<p>The word "<span data-info="think">thought</span>" may be new to elementary learners.</p>
```

(The span's `data-info` attribute provides information which is used later — when the user hovers the mouse over the word — to display images, definitions and examples, but that is not important here.)

The text comes from non-web-developer authors, and it contains no mark-up at all at the beginning. I am writing two tools: one offline and one online. The offline tool compares the vocabulary with lists of words that students are expected to know at different levels, and allows an non-tech-savvy editor to collect different inflections of the same word (for example: lose|loses|lost|losing) that appear in the given text, so that they can be treated as the same root word. This generates an array of terms that the student might want to learn more about. Each term is stored as a string that can be converted to a regular expression. For example `"los(?:e|es|t|ing)"`.

The online web page will receive:

- The raw text from the author
- The array of search terms
- Some more information about what reference sites to use. This information will be added to the data-info attribute of the enclosing span, but it is not important here.

The online code will work through the array, looking for matches for each regular expression (`/thought|thinks?/`, for example) in the raw text and add the same span to all the occurrences it finds. It will also add `<p>` tags where necessary.

However, the word "thought" can be either a verb or a noun: "Yesterday I thought..." (verb) or "Yesterday I had a thought... " (noun). In the second case, I need to use a different regular expression: /thoughts?/, to allow for both singular and plural forms.

However, both these regular expressions will find a match for "thought", which is the problem I need to solve.

This is where the "information hiding" comes in. One solution would be for my offline tool to add tags to the raw text like this...

Yesterday I thought ... Yesterday I had a thought ...

I can then use different regular expressions for each case, and there would be no clash.

```
/<verb>(thought|thinks?)<\/verb>/
/<noun>(thoughts?)<\/noun>/
```

Since these tags will be not be displayed in the browser, they can remain in place ... or can they?

Is there any danger in using non-standard and non-declared tags in this way?

Comment: You can't use `display: none;` css? Also do not parse html with regex.

Comment: A "do not parse html regex" diktat seems over-zealous in this case. The HTML is very simple and under my control. But thanks for the reminder to be careful. https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2013/02/21/can-regular-expressions-parse-html-or-not/

Answer (score 1):

Why don't wrap it with a span like you did at the beginning and add an attribute called "data-type".

Would give :

```
<p>Yesterday I <span data-info="think" data-type="verb">thought</<span> ... Yesterday I had a <span data-info="think" data-type="noun">thought</span> ... <p>
```

Comment: I've added more info to the question to answer your question.